# How do I get an inline-block text element to have a correct width when wrapped?

Tags: html, css

Given a series of inline-block items, contained within a flexible width column, I need each item to be outlined based on their actual width.

Major considerations are:

- The text is wrapped, depending on the width of the column
- The border should collapse down as much as possible. In other words, it should hug the right most side of the text.

**Examples - Correct**

```
+--flexible width container --+
|                             |
|+-------+                    |
||hello  |                    |
||goodbye|                    |
|+-------+                    |
|                             |
|+---------------+            |
||la da de da bla|            |
||hello          |            |
|+---------------+            |
+-----------------------------+
```

**Examples - Wrong**

```
+---- flexible width container ----+
|                                  |
|+--------------------------------+|
||Hello goodbye                   ||
||super_long_word_gets_wrapped    ||
|+--------------------------------+|
+----------------------------------+
```

**Important Note**
See how when a long word gets wrapped, the border gets pushed all the way out. That is because the text element is considered to be the width if the word hadn't been wrapped.

[image]

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/kvLkxf21/1/

It's also worth noting that the following isn't acceptable because in Firefox the border doesn't go around the whole element, it creates multiple boxes, one for each line.

http://jsfiddle.net/kvLkxf21/8/

```
<div>
    <p>hello hello</p>
    <p>hello hello, how12345</p>
    <p>goodbye</p>
</div>


div {
    width:120px;    
}

p {
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Use `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: didn't get your question..

Comment: I should have mentioned that it is inline-block

Comment: I don't think this is possible with css alone

Comment: @Danield Cheers, I was thinking maybe that too, but thought I would throw it into the bullpit anyway

Comment: @Chris - however with `display: table-caption;` you can get close to what you want [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvLkxf21/7/)

Comment: Hmm, this seems so close. Firefox is having issues (only shows the first element ?!?!), but works in chrome....